# GWT Permutation for browser

Tags: gwt, browser

Can someone tell me in GWT, when the compiler generates the war file, in which folder does it store the javaScript files for every browser??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the folder you specified in your .gwt.xml file: In

```
<module rename-to="mymodule">
```

it's the folder "mymodule".

The JavaScript files have names like "19F721DD4BCFB147198D3EC97B70ACD5.cache.html". Yes, the suffix is ".html", although it's JavaScript. The GWT FAQ [says about this](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/FAQ_DebuggingAndCompiling.html#What%27s_with_all_the_cache/nocache_stuff_and_weird_filenames):

> The reason for this is that certain browsers do not correctly handle compression of pure-JavaScript files in some circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Where they are is usually in your "module name dir" in your war dir. To generate them you need to set them up in your module xml config file:

```
<module rename-to="moduleName">
      <!-- blah blah -->
      <set-property name="user.agent" value="ie6,gecko,gecko1_8" />
      <!-- generate perms for IE and firefox only -->
</module>
```